# Convert a div into a span with DOMdocument

Tags: php, dom, domdocument

How can I convert this structure

```
<div class="parent"> 
   <div class="someclass">
       <b>some HTML</b>
       ...
   </div>
   <div class="someclass">
       <b>some HTML</b>
       ...
   </div>
</div>
```

into

```
<div class="parent">
   <span class="someclass">
       <b>some HTML</b>
       ...
   </span>
   <span class="someclass">
       <b>some HTML</b>
       ...
   </span>
</div>
```

I have valid HTML markup, but since there are many other div's I can't do a preg_replace.

I like a server side solution (PHP)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a PHP example of using `DOM Document`, `DOM Element` and `DOM Node` to replace your div with a span. Whether or not it's the most efficient way... I'm not entirely certain.

**PHP CODE**

```
$Dom = new DOMDocument();
$Dom->loadHTML('<div id="someid"><b>some HTML</b>...</div>');

$Ele = $Dom->getElementById('someid');
$New = $Dom->createElement('span', $Ele->nodeValue);
$New->setAttribute('id', $Ele->getAttribute('id'));
$Parent = $Ele->parentNode;
$Parent->removeChild($Ele);
$Parent->appendChild($New);

echo $Dom->saveHTML();
```

**PHP Response from `echo`**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body><span id="someid">some HTML...</span></body></html>
```

You could probably use `DOM Fragment` to ignore all the html, body and doctype tags.

Comment: I'm trying with a couple of elements and with classes witch doesn't work:  
 $xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
 $modulecontainer = $xpath->query("//*/div[@class='myclass']");
  
 foreach( $modulecontainer as $container) {

  $new = $doc->createElement('span', $container->nodeValue);
  $parent = $container->parentNode;
  $parent->removeChild($container);
  $parent->appendChild($new);
   
 }

Comment: also it doesn't preserve the html in the child node

Answer (score -3):

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="test" style="color:blue;">test</div>
</div>
<script>
var container = document.getElementById("container");
var html = container.innerHTML.replace(new RegExp("<div","g"),"<span");
html = html.replace(new RegExp("<\/div","g"),"</span");
container.innerHTML = html;
</script>
```

Comment: Don't use regex on HTML, -1